# How Can I Enable CORS on NGINX?

Tags: nginx, cors

I'm attempting to enable CORS on NGINX to get around Same Origin Policy for some Ajax.  I've followed a few guides, but they aren't working.  Here is my current nginx.conf and default.conf.  What am I doing wrong?

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user              nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;    
    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

default.conf

```
#
# The default server
#

map $http_origin $cors_header {
    default "";
    "~^http?://[^/]+\.wplivestats\.com(:[0-9]+)?$" "$http_origin";
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name wplivestats.com;

    location / {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors_header;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    }

location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
expires 365d;
}


    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: The regular expression and configuration you're using say that resources from wplivestats.com will be allowed to be requested from sites with domains like *.wplivestats.com . Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Check out these link: http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Comment: I confirm, that the link http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html works.